# Horizontal alignment of an image

Tags: css, html, centering

I am trying to horizontally center a large image. Because I am using HTML5, I can't use `<center>`. I could use `left:400px`, but that wouldn't work for different screen sizes.

Comment: False. The `center` tag will work, it just isn't semantic anymore. HTML5 depreciated the tag, for a good cause.

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the image inside an element and use `text-align: center;`...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/)

```
<div class="center">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" alt="Google" />
</div>

.center {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Alternatively if you are aware, that what's the image width, you can also use `margin: auto;` with `display: block;` as `img` tag is `inline` element by default and of course, the `width` property

```
img {
   width: 276px;
   display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/1/)

Comment: The alternative solution with "display: block;" and "margin: auto;" worked fine for me.

Comment: From Praveen's answer, it looks like `width` is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this css to horizontally center

```
display: block;    
margin: 0 auto;
```

= the top and bottom margin `0`, and the left and right margin `auto`

Comment: I don't know who up voted this.. but this is completely wrong, `img` is an inline element by default, you cannot use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it

Comment: @Mr.Alien It worked for me.  Took a sample from your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/2/)

Comment: Because you are using display block :) and you've mentioned no where in your answer that you should use `display: block;` in order to work :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry. I should've added it.  Thanks :) for pointing my mistake.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Yea, even I've used that, so I've mentioned it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `text-align: center;`.  And don't forget to set width on the div or it will look left-aligned.

```
  <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">Centered</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `element` has the `width` property , then give it `margin:auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific situation, this has worked for me on several projects:

```
<style>
    .outer{float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;}
    .inner{float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;}
</style>
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner">content you want to center, image, text, whatevs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a slightly different method to this, involving left and margin-left working together (against each other actually) in the same way, but it requires setting the exact half of the image size which doesn't work as well in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The IMG element is inline, by default. So, as the others have pointed, you have two options:

1) Keep it inline, and use `text-align: center;`.

2) Make it a block element with `display: block;`, and then use `margin: auto;`, which works only on block elements. I think this solution is better. Setting the width is just another way to force it to be a block element, but it's less obvious for someone that may read the code later. So explicitly setting the `display` type to `block` is better for readability.